# Display proportional circles on a map with R

Tags: r

I have data stored in a data.frame :

| Points | Numbers |
| --- | --- |
| 41.53329498,3.86258704 | 3 |
| 41.54960312,3.70673344 | 6 |
| 41.54961245,3.77906700 | 20 |

I want to display the points in a map with an OSM background from the geographical coordinates (WGS84) and vary the circle with the associated value.

I tried several libraries combining ggplot2 and ggspatial but I could not display the points.

Comment: ggforce::geom_circle?

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure how valid is it, but I´m not in here for point, I tried your question on chatgpt

[image: map]

with this code it presented

```
# Install and load required packages
install.packages("leaflet")
library(leaflet)

# Create a data frame with the given data
df <- data.frame(
  Points = c("41.53329498,3.86258704", "41.54960312,3.70673344", "41.54961245,3.77906700"),
  Numbers = c(3, 6, 20)
)

# Extract latitude and longitude from the Points column
df$Latitude <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(df$Points, ","), "[[", 1))
df$Longitude <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(df$Points, ","), "[[", 2))

# Create a leaflet map
map <- leaflet(df) %>%
  addTiles()  # Add OSM tiles as the background

# Add circle markers to the map
map <- map %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    lng = ~Longitude,  # Longitude values from the data frame
    lat = ~Latitude,   # Latitude values from the data frame
    radius = ~Numbers,  # Vary the circle radius with the Numbers column
    color = "blue",     # Circle color
    fillOpacity = 0.7   # Circle fill opacity
  )

# Display the map
map
```

I think it could be a good start point to go.

Comment: Fyi, content from chatgpt is currently , banned https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: ... though `leaflet` would have been my recommendation as well

Comment: @r2evans thanks, I didn´t know, I´m going to refrain, anyway is going to get more and more hard to detect it in near future anyway.

Comment: I agree that it is going to be difficult to enforce. They penned it as "temporary", I expect they are looking for ways to detect and flag for review, or some other policy that will eventually acknowledge the *potential* for inclusion. I'm all for using chatgpt as a source of ideas, from which one can verify and refine the code for an answer. I'm opposed to using chatgpt code without said verification, especially in areas of programming with which the user has little experience, preferring answers to be written by those with "real experience".

Answer (score 0):

As `sf` and `ggplot` play so well together, I'd just use those here too even though `ggspatial` would allow to skip `sf`. For finer control over points / circles, you could create circular buffered around points (`sf::st_buffer()`) this would allow you to define the actual radius in meters.

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
read.table(header = TRUE, 
           text = "Points   Numbers
                   41.53329498,3.86258704   3
                   41.54960312,3.70673344   6
                   41.54961245,3.77906700   20") |> 
  separate_wider_delim(Points, delim = ",", names = c("lat", "lon")) |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "WGS84") |>
  ggplot() +
  # rosm::osm.types() lists available tile types
  annotation_map_tile(type = "cartolight", zoomin = -1) +
  geom_sf(aes(size = Numbers), color = "darkred") +
  annotation_scale() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(2.4,4), ylim = c(41.4, 42)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>